# Single way to show title based on Filters recommendation

Tags: php

I have a form with 5 options to filter data from mysql (start date, end date, user, course, level)  and i would like to present a title with a custom text based on the selection, like if the user only choose dates, the title would say "Data from start date to end date), if the user choose user, then would be "Data for user from start date to end date, and so on. 
Its a headache to make all possible combinations using if option 1 != "" && option2 == "" etc. In this case i have 25 possible combinations, there is any recommendation to handle this easily and thinking that if in a future i would like to add another filter that would be 30 combinations and i would have to rewrite the if again. Sorry if its a silly question but i dont see it another way clearly right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify:

```
$output = "";
if($user != ""){
      $output .= "User: " . $user . " ";
}
if($dateFrom != ""){
      $output .= "Start date: " . $dateFrom . " ";
}
if($dateTo != ""){
      $output .= "End date: " . $dateTo . " ";
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: Thanks bro! this is the most clean way for me

Comment: :) I have faced this situation recently and I have used something similar

Answer (score 0):

You can build a message for user for example that way:

```
$response = "";

if($user_filter == true)
{
   if($response == "")
   {
        $response = "Data for user: ".$some_user;
   }
   eles
   {
        $response = $response." and from user: ".$some_user;
   }
}

if($date_filter == true)
{
   if($response == "")
   {
        $response = "Data from ".$start_date." to ".$end_date;
   }
   eles
   {
        $response = $response." and from ".$start_date." to ".$end_date;
   }
}
```

So that way you will and for each filter just one if...